# over voltage detection using comparator

Tags: operational-amplifier, comparator

I need to design a over voltage protection circuit.
I intend to use a comparator for the said circuit. The reference will be from a standard voltage ref source. While the voltage at the non-inverting terminal would be the output of voltage bus.

Now, based on the comparator truth table - if the 2 are equal the output is zero and if the Vsupply is greater than reference the output is high. Now, wouldnt small spikes in the Vsupply(to the non inv terminal) be a source of voltage corruption ?
How can I ensure a smooth dc level here ?

Also, suppose I want to send the output of the comparator to 2 different MOSFETS,I understand that I cannot just supply it directly as the sourcing current of comparator might not be enough. I might have to have a driver. Would a transistor be sufficient in this case ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can add hysteresis using positive feedback from the comparator output.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1Pg1o.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Of course, the amount of hysteresis you add depends on how noisy you expect your signals to be.

Comment: Adding small capacitors might also help to smooth the voltages.

Comment: R1 is superflous here.

Comment: what do you mean superflous ?

Comment: It's not doing anything. It could just be a wire. The important components are R2 and R3